# Why do i have segmentation fault (core dumped) in this example but in the first one not?

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

im building a simple bank account program for my computer science class which reads a file and outputs the records.(c - create,y-credit account,d-debit account, t transaction, r-remove only if positive)
I made the program which which works for this example:

```
c Ann y
c Bob n
c Carl y
t Ann +200.00
t Bob -50.0
t Carl -20.05
t Dan +1000.0
r Carl
t Bob +30.0
r Ann
c Bob y
```

And outputs:

```
error on line 5: account cannot hold negative balance
error on line 7: account does not exist
error on line 8: account holds negative balance
error on line 11: account already exists

Bob owns 30 euros
Carl owes 20.05 euros
```

But for this example:

```
c Ann y

c Bob n

t Ann +534.50

t Bob +40.00

t Bob -45.99

t Ann -200.00

c Carl y

c Dan y

c Eric n

t Ann -94.99

t Dan +94.99

t Carl -20.00

t Dan +20.00

r Carl

c Bob y

t Dan -15.00

t Eric +15.00

r Dan

t Eric -5.00

t Bob +5.00

t Ann -139.51

t Bob +69.75

t Carl +69.75

r Eric

r Dan
```

It outputs:

```
error on line 5: account cannot hold negative balance
error on line 14: account holds negative balance
error on line 15: Account already exists
error on line 19: account cannot hold negative balance
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

void error(std::string str)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(str);
}

class Account
{
    private:

        float money;               
        char type, name[15];        

    public:

        Account(char t, const char* n);
        char* getName();
        float getMoney();
        void setMoney(float m);
        char getType();

};

Account::Account(char t,const char* n)
{
    money = 0;
    type = t;
    strcpy(name,n);

}


float Account::getMoney()
{
    return money;
}

void Account::setMoney(float m)
{
    money = m;
}

char Account::getType()
{
    return type;
}

char* Account::getName() // get name of the account
{
    return name;
}

Account* getAccount(std::vector <Account> &allAccounts, std::string name) // in needed reference here so i didnt need to create another function to copy
{
    for(int i = 0; i < allAccounts.size(); i++)  // goint through the accounts
        if(strcmp(allAccounts[i].getName(), name.c_str()) == 0)

            return &allAccounts[i];
    return NULL;
}

int getAccountIndex(std::vector <Account> allAccounts, std::string name) // Assumes the account exists in vector
{
    for(int i = 0; i < allAccounts.size(); i++)
        if(strcmp(allAccounts[i].getName(), name.c_str()) == 0)

            return i;
}

int main()
{
    int line = 0;
    std::ifstream in("accounts.txt");
    std::vector <Account> allAccounts;

    while(true)
    {
        line++;
        char cmd;
        in >> cmd;

        if(in.eof()) // end of file. If it's empty, theres no reason to go through the loop
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        std::string name;
        in >> name;

        switch(cmd)
        {

            case 'c':

                char type;
                in >> type;
                try
                {
                   if(getAccount(allAccounts,name) != NULL)
                   {
                       error("Account already exists");
                   }
                   Account a(type, name.c_str());
                   allAccounts.push_back(a);

                }
                 catch(std::runtime_error& error)
                {
                    std::cerr << "error on line " << line <<": "<< error.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;

            case 't':
            {

                float sum;
                in >> sum;

                Account* pa = getAccount(allAccounts,name); // assign in memory

                try
                {
                    if(pa == NULL)
                    {
                        error("account does not exist");
                    }

                    if(pa->getType() == 'n' && sum < 0)
                    {
                        error("account cannot hold negative balance");
                    }
                    pa->setMoney(pa->getMoney() + sum);
                }

                catch(std::runtime_error& error)
                {
                    std::cerr << "error on line " << line <<": "<< error.what() << std::endl;
                }

                break;
            }

            case 'r':

                Account* pa = getAccount(allAccounts,name);
                int i = getAccountIndex(allAccounts,name);
                 try
                {
                    if(pa->getMoney() < 0)
                    {
                        error("account holds negative balance");
                    }

                    allAccounts.erase(allAccounts.begin()+i);

                }

                catch(std::runtime_error& error)
                {
                    std::cerr << "error on line " << line <<": "<< error.what() << std::endl;
                }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < allAccounts.size();i++)
    {
        Account a = allAccounts[i];

        std::cout << a.getName() << " ";
        if(a.getMoney() > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "owns " << a.getMoney() << " Euros" << std::endl;
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "owes " << -a.getMoney() << " Euros" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: At first glance, I see that `getAccount` can return NULL but some of your code assumes that it will never return NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            Account* pa = getAccount(allAccounts,name);
            int i = getAccountIndex(allAccounts,name);
             try
            {
                if(pa->getMoney() < 0)
                {
                    error("account holds negative balance");
                }

                allAccounts.erase(allAccounts.begin()+i);

            }

            catch(std::runtime_error& error)
            {
                std::cerr << "error on line " << line <<": "<< error.what() << std::endl;
            }
```

There's no check if `pa` is `NULL` before `pa->getMoney()`. So you blow up in the `r Dan` line. You are not allowed to invoke a member function on anything but a valid object.

Comment: OMG thank you, you saved my life!! i have been  looking for hours and my deadline is in 1 hour. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Edward You need to learn how to use a debugger then. Post-mortem debugging is as easy as waiting for the program to crash and then looking at the stack and variables.

Comment: Yeah, it is my 7th week in computer science class, i'm still a beginner.

Comment: @Edward take the time. The return on investment from learning to use the debugger is sick. You will likely lose a few hours in figuring out the debugger software and make it all up by debugging the next assignment in a fraction of the time. Be the envy of your classmates by getting your work done early enough to go out for a few drinks.